# @ComponentScan in Spring (not Boot) doesn't scans subpackages

Tags: spring, component-scan

My project is situated in package home.bank_application. There are a lot of subpackages, such as 'controller', 'dao', 'service', 'config' etc...
When  I annotated my WebConfigClass as `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "home.bank_application")` my subpackages aren't scaned.

When I annotated my WebConfigClass as `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"home.bank_application.controller", "home.bank_application.dao","home.bank_application.service", "home.bank_application.config"})`, all these packages are scaned fine.
But when  I annotated my WebConfigClass as `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "home.bank_application")` my subpackages aren't scaned.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem.
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "home.bank_application")
and
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "home.bank_application.*")
NOT the same things.
All problem was in `*` in the end of path!!!

Comment: There's no `.*` in your question